# Retrieve path information from PathTooLongException

Tags: c#, .net, windows, path, pathtoolongexception

I am using DirectoryInfo and FileInfo in .Net 4.0 to enumerate files in a directory tree and I am hitting PathTooLongException. Simplified version is below

```cs
public static class Test
{
    public static void Search(DirectoryInfo base)
    {
        foreach(var file in base.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
            } catch(PathTooLongException ex)
            {
                // What path was this?
            }
        }
        foreach(var dir in base.GetDirectories())
        {
            Search(dir);
        }
    }
}
```

When the error is thrown, I want to know what file path caused the problem. Obviously I can't ask for `FullName` as that is what errored. I can get name from `file.Name`, but if I can't get the rest of the path as `file.Directory` gives a `PathTooLongException` even though the `DirectoryInfo` that the file was found from worked fine! (I can't use that though as the actual code is much more complex).

Looking through the stack trace it seems that it's using an internal path (I see a protected `file.FullPath` from debug), and trying to tear the directory from the full (oversized) path. Most of the problems seem to involve `System.IO.Path.NormalizePath`, with I hear went through a few changes in .Net 4.0. I have not tried on previous versions of the framework.

My questions:

1. How can I get the full path from this exception; it is seemingly passed without any useful information.
2. Why would the framework need to limit characters in a path to chop off the filename?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Andy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't think of any other way off the top of my head other than using reflection, or using a library or P/Invoke to use the Windows APIs that support long paths and manually check length.  The full path is stored in a `protected string` field called `FullPath`

```
foreach(var dir in new DirectoryInfo (@"D:\longpaths")
                     .GetFileSystemInfos("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dir.FullName);
    }
    catch (PathTooLongException)
    {
                FieldInfo fld = typeof(FileSystemInfo).GetField(
                                        "FullPath", 
                                         BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                         BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                Console.WriteLine(fld.GetValue(dir));  // outputs your long path
    }
}
```

If you're trying to *actually* do something with the files and not just check file length, I would suggest using a library like this one [from the BCL team at Microsoft](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Long%20Path%20Samples&referringTitle=Long%20Path), however it doesn't create `DirectoryInfos`, `FileInfo` or `FileSystemInfo`, only strings.  So it's might not be a drop-in replacement for your code it seems.

As for the answer to your second question, I recommend reading [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx) dealing with long paths in .NET.  This is a quote from it that explains why they haven't been quick to add long path support in .NET.

> Very few people complain about a 32K limit, so, problem solved? Not quite. There are several reasons we were reluctant to add long paths in the past, and why we’re still careful about it, related to security, inconsistent support in the Windows APIs of the \?\ syntax, and app compatibility.

It's a 3 part series and explains a few reasons why the API is the way it is and why the limitation is there.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I feared this would be the case. It just seems silly to hold the path privately and not allow access to it without validating it first...even though it created the invalid path for me just fine.
The `LongPath` library you pointed to looks great! Unfortunately I forgot to mention all the paths will be UNC so won't be able to use as is (yet). Will be very useful to look through the code though to see how to implement the direct API.

Comment: @Andyrooger, yeah, I forgot about that.  I forked the code and added that in a while ago.  You can get the code [at its codeplex project](http://longpaths.codeplex.com/).  Use the source code, not the release, I fixed a silly bug.

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens +1 for the FieldInfo tip!